# 40:232: execution error: -e:1:in `load': cannot load such file -- install (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, bundler, gem-bundler

Trying to setup Cucumber, Watir and RubyMine.

Create a cucumber test and trying to do a bundle install and keep getting the error.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e  $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) install
40:232: execution error: -e:1:in `load': cannot load such file -- install (LoadError)
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
 (1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I do not even know where to look for this issues, is this a RubyMine issue or not required Gem issue?

Ruby 2.3.0

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: I wonder who had upvoted this question.

Comment: you say 'trying to do bundle install'   So please, how exactly are you trying to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to understand what you are trying to achieve, but the behaviour is clear:

1. you call ruby script `load($0=ARGV.shift)` (setting globals makes no impact and omitted for clarity) inline;
2. you pass a command line argument `install` to it;
3. `ARGV.shift` extracts the first command line argument (`install`) and passes it to `load`;
4. `load` fails giving you the error message.

This issue:

1. has nothing to do with cucumber;
2. has nothing to do with RubyMine;
3. has nothing to do with required gems.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your Gemfile or gemspec you have dependency on a bundler gem that can not be satisfied.  Like:

```
spec.add_development_dependency 'bundler', '~> 1.10'
```

But you only have bundler 1.13.1 installed.  RubyMine can't handle this situation correctly and you get described error.

Remove or update version specification in your Gemfile (or gemspec).